# Rowcount returns 1 but no records in the table

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using `mycursor.rowcount` return 1 as result but there is nothing in the database table.
`SELECT * FROM result_sizeer` return 0 rows.

```
import requests
import csv
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="****************",
  database="scrape"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS result_sizeer")
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE result_sizeer (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) NULL, sku VARCHAR(255) NULL, price DOUBLE NULL)")
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO result_sizeer (id, name, sku, price) VALUES ('6','asd','zxc','111')")
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
exit("END")
```

No errors thrown. Everything seems to work fine. Using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If autocommit is not enabled then try to issue a commit manually.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!